# Animation flickers and changing sprites in MonoGame

Tags: c#, monogame, 2d-games

**A video that shows the problem [Video](https://youtu.be/jTnuEAnqEIg)**
I just started working with Monogame and I've added to my game some characters and animation but something really strange is happening.
If you will look on the video on the first time I run the game. When the character lands the color of the base of her shoe is changing from black to white for no reason (There is no white sole texture in the game files).

On the third time I ran the game you can see when one character jumps the other character shoes freaks out again for no reason.
I have no problem to give all the game files and textures I have zero clue on way it's happening.
Thanks in advance:)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like an issue with the tint color in your Draw()-Call. Use Color.White for full color with no tinting.

E.g: spriteBatch.Draw(player.Texture, player.Position, Color.White);